# regEx finding unique string

Tags: regex, shell

I have a header ind a file format:

```
@3d886d0d-a260-4c2d-b3de-7b05fee9ec6a runid=8234a809c305f32bf08994f578af0b1464b16de1 read=114 ch=336 start_time=2019-09-10T12:25:24Z flow_id=XXX protocol_group_id=XXX sample_id=XXX 
GTTACCTTGTTACGACTTCACCCAGTCATGAACCACACCGTGGTAAACGCCCTCCCGAAGGTTAAGCTATCTACTTCTGGTGCAGCCCACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGGCGGTGTGTACAAGGCCAGGAACATATTCACCGTGACATTCTGATTCACGATTACCAAAATTCCGACTTCATGGAGTCGAGTTGCGAACTCCAATCCGGACTGACGTACTTTGTAGGATTCGCTCACTATCCCTTTAACTTACTACGCCATTGTAGCACGTGTGTAGCCCTCTCGTAAGGGCCATGATGATGACGTCGTCCCCACCTTCCTCCGGTTTTATCACCGGCAGTCTCCTAATTCCCACCATTACGTGCTGGCAAACAAGGATAAGGGTTGCTTCGTTGGGACTTAACAACATTTCACAACACGAGCTGACGACAGCCATGCAGCACCTGTCTCCAGAGTTCCAGAGGCACTAAGCTATCTCTAGCGAATTCTCTGGATGTCAGAGTAGGTGCATCAGAATTAAACCACCACCGCTTGTGCGGGCCCCGTCAATTCATTTGGAGTTTTAATCTTGCGATAGCACTCCCCAGGCGGTCATAACGCGTTAGCTCCGAAAGCCACGGCTCAAGGCCACAACCTTCAAGTAGACATCGTTTACGGCGTGGACTACCAGGGTATCTAATCCTGTTTTGCTCCCACGCTTTCATCTGAGCGTCAGTCTTTGTCAGGGGCCGCCTTCGCCACCGGTATTCCTTCAGATCTCACGCATTTCACCGCTACACCTGAAATTCTACCCCCTCTGGAACTCCCTAGTCTGCCAGTTCTTTGTTCGAGTTGAAAGACCCCAGGCTTTCCACATCCTGTAACAAACCGCCTGCATGCGCTTAGTAATTCCGGTAACGCTCACTTTACCCTCCGTATTACCGCGGCTGCTAGGCACGGAGTTAGCCGGTGCTTCTTCTGTTGCTAACGTCCAAGCGCTGAAGCTATTAACTCCAACGCCTTCCTCTAACTGAAAGTACTTTACAACCGAAGGCCTTCTTCATACACACGCGAGCATGGCTGCATCAGGGTTTCCCCATTGTGCAATATTTACTGCTCCCACGCAGGAAGTCTGGACGTGTCTCAGTTCCAGTGTGGCTGATCATCCTCAGACCAGCTAGGATCGTCGCCTTGGTGACCATTACCCCACCAACTAGCTAATCCACCTGGGCTAATCACGACTGAGAGGCGAAGGTCCCCTCTTTGCTCCGAAGAGATTATGCCTCGTTTCCAATAGTTATCCCCCACATCAGGGTATATTCCCAGGCATTACTCACCCGTCCGCCGCTCGTCAGCAAAAAGAAAGCAAGCTTCCTTTCTGTTACCGCTCGACTTGCATGTGTTAGGCCTGCCGCCAGCACCAATCTGAGCCATGGTCAAACT
+
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
```

I need to identify the header and add additional text, my "barcode" at the end of the header line. The number of tab seperated variables in the header varies. In this case the barcode should be added after "sample_id=XXX".

Ideally, the header would end up with:

```
@3d886d0d-a260-4c2d-b3de-7b05fee9ec6a runid=8234a809c305f32bf08994f578af0b1464b16de1 read=114 ch=336 start_time=2019-09-10T12:25:24Z flow_id=XXX protocol_group_id=XXX sample_id=XXX$ barcode=barcodeXX
```

Unfortunatly is `sed -i -E "s/^@[^ \t]+([ \t]+[^ \t=]+=[^ \t]+)*/& $BARCODETAG/" $filename`
 not sufficient as the text may start with a @, and will the following output.

```
@d03b78bb-9ed5-4891-96bc-a1408d163ddc runid=8234a809c305f32bf08994f578af0b1464b16de1 read=360 ch=303 start_time=2019-09-10T12:26:42Z flow_id=XXX protocol_group_id=XXX sample_id=XXX $ barcode=barcode03
GTTTGATCATGGCTCAGGATGAACGCTGGCGGCGTGCCTAACATGCAAGTCGAACGCACAGCGAAAGGTGCTTGCCTTTCAAGTGAGTGGCGAACGGGTGAGTAACACGTGGACAACCTGCCTCAAGGCTGGGGATAACATTTGGAAACAGATGCTAATACCGAATAAAACTTAGTGTCGCATGACACAAAGTTAAGAGCGCTTCGGCGTCACCTAGAATGGATCCGCAGTGCATTAGTTAGTTGGTGTAGGCCTACCAAGACAATGATGCATAGCCGAGTTGAAGACTGATCAGCCACGTGGGACTGAGACTTTAAGCTCCTACAGGAGGCTGCAGTAGGAATCTTCCACAATGGGCGAAAGCGCAGTGGAACAACGCCGCGTGTGTGATGAAGGCTTTCGGGTCGTAAACACTGTTGTATGGGAAGAACAGCTAAGAATAAGGAAATGATTTTAGTTTGACGGTACCATACCAGAAAGTTGACTAAATACGTGCCCAGCCGCGTAATATGTGCGAGCGTTATCCGGATTTATTG
+
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barcode=barcode03
```

I belive that specifically the structure of the start of the header 
`@xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx`
  (the 5th field differs in the number of characters) or 
`@ XXXX runid=`
are the most unique identifiers

---

Okay, sry, here we go again :)

So its only in the top header i need to add the "barcode" at the end of the entire header. In this case after "sample_id=XXX".

Due to the "@"s in the 4th line, the "barcode" is added to the end of this line as well.

```
@3d886d0d-a260-4c2d-b3de-7b05fee9ec6a runid=8234a809c305f32bf08994f578af0b1464b16de1 read=114 ch=336 start_time=2019-09-10T12:25:24Z flow_id=XXX protocol_group_id=XXX sample_id=XXX 
GTTACCTTGTTACGACTTCACCCAGTCATGAACCACACCGTGGTAAACGCCCTCCCGAAGGTTAAGCTATCTACTTCTGGTGCAGCCCACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGGCGGTGTGTACAAGGCCAGGAACATATTCACCGTGACATTCTGATTCACGATTACCAAAATTCCGACTTCATGGAGTCGAGTTGCGAACTCCAATCCGGACTGACGTACTTTGTAGGATTCGCTCACTATCCCTTTAACTTACTACGCCATTGTAGCACGTGTGTAGCCCTCTCGTAAGGGCCATGATGATGACGTCGTCCCCACCTTCCTCCGGTTTTATCACCGGCAGTCTCCTAATTCCCACCATTACGTGCTGGCAAACAAGGATAAGGGTTGCTTCGTTGGGACTTAACAACATTTCACAACACGAGCTGACGACAGCCATGCAGCACCTGTCTCCAGAGTTCCAGAGGCACTAAGCTATCTCTAGCGAATTCTCTGGATGTCAGAGTAGGTGCATCAGAATTAAACCACCACCGCTTGTGCGGGCCCCGTCAATTCATTTGGAGTTTTAATCTTGCGATAGCACTCCCCAGGCGGTCATAACGCGTTAGCTCCGAAAGCCACGGCTCAAGGCCACAACCTTCAAGTAGACATCGTTTACGGCGTGGACTACCAGGGTATCTAATCCTGTTTTGCTCCCACGCTTTCATCTGAGCGTCAGTCTTTGTCAGGGGCCGCCTTCGCCACCGGTATTCCTTCAGATCTCACGCATTTCACCGCTACACCTGAAATTCTACCCCCTCTGGAACTCCCTAGTCTGCCAGTTCTTTGTTCGAGTTGAAAGACCCCAGGCTTTCCACATCCTGTAACAAACCGCCTGCATGCGCTTAGTAATTCCGGTAACGCTCACTTTACCCTCCGTATTACCGCGGCTGCTAGGCACGGAGTTAGCCGGTGCTTCTTCTGTTGCTAACGTCCAAGCGCTGAAGCTATTAACTCCAACGCCTTCCTCTAACTGAAAGTACTTTACAACCGAAGGCCTTCTTCATACACACGCGAGCATGGCTGCATCAGGGTTTCCCCATTGTGCAATATTTACTGCTCCCACGCAGGAAGTCTGGACGTGTCTCAGTTCCAGTGTGGCTGATCATCCTCAGACCAGCTAGGATCGTCGCCTTGGTGACCATTACCCCACCAACTAGCTAATCCACCTGGGCTAATCACGACTGAGAGGCGAAGGTCCCCTCTTTGCTCCGAAGAGATTATGCCTCGTTTCCAATAGTTATCCCCCACATCAGGGTATATTCCCAGGCATTACTCACCCGTCCGCCGCTCGTCAGCAAAAAGAAAGCAAGCTTCCTTTCTGTTACCGCTCGACTTGCATGTGTTAGGCCTGCCGCCAGCACCAATCTGAGCCATGGTCAAACT
+
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
```

Ideally, the header would end up with:

```
@3d886d0d-a260-4c2d-b3de-7b05fee9ec6a runid=8234a809c305f32bf08994f578af0b1464b16de1 read=114 ch=336 start_time=2019-09-10T12:25:24Z flow_id=XXX protocol_group_id=XXX sample_id=XXX$ barcode=barcodeXX
```

Comment: Looks like you want `sed -i "s/\(@[^[:space:]][^[:space:]]*\) \(runid=\)/\1 $BARCODETAG \2/" $filename;`

Comment: Almost :) Now it just adds "BARCODETAG" right before "runid", whil ei want it at the end of the header

Comment: And where is the end of the header? After `runid=...`? If yes, try `sed -i -E "s/@[^[:space:]]+ runid=[^[:space:]]+/& $BARCODETAG/" $filename;`

Comment: Sorry the the lack of information. The entire header CAN be ```@3d886d0d-a260-4c2d-b3de-7b05fee9ec6a runid=8234a809c305f32bf08994f578af0b1464b16de1 read=114 ch=336 start_time=2019-09-10T12:25:24Z flow_id=XXX protocol_group_id=XXX sample_id=XXX``` The number of tab seperated variables in the header varies. So is there a way to just always add the "barcode" to the end of the header?

Comment: So, after this text there is some other text still on the line? Then try `sed -i -E "s/@[^ \t]+([ \t]+[^ \t=]+=[^ \t]+)*/& $BARCODETAG/" $filename`

Comment: Well it now adds the barcode to the text after the header if it finds a @. Additionally, and "space" is addet before the "$". Is it possible to have no space there? - thanks so much

Comment: Please share the test case in the question body, it is extremely difficult to help without exact test cases and requirements

Comment: So, the solution above works, right? See https://ideone.com/Uk722X.

Comment: Unfortunatly not. The barcode is still added at the end of the text  as well, and its only in the header the barcode is to be added.

Comment: Ah, add `^` at the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -i -E "s/^@[[:xdigit:]]{8}(-[[:xdigit:]]{4}){3}-[[:xdigit:]]+([ \t]+[^ \t=]+=[^ \t]+)*/& $BARCODETAG/" file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/tNAJKv)

The pattern will match

- `^` - start of string
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[[:xdigit:]]{8}(-[[:xdigit:]]{4}){3}-[[:xdigit:]]+` - 8 hex chars, 3 occurrences of `-` and then 4 hex chars, `-`, 1+ hex chars
- `([ \t]+[^ \t=]+=[^ \t]+)*` - 0 or more occurrences of 1+ spaces/tabs followed with 1+ chars other than space, tab and `=` chars, then `=` and then 1+ chars other than space and tab.

The `&` in the replacement part inserts the whole match found.

Mind the `-E` flag, it is necessary to make `+` work as a quantifier and `(...)` as capturing parentheses.

Comment: It works, except that ```-[[:xdigit:]]{12}``` is not a uniqe identifyer. The field may differ in number of characters. If this part is removed, the barcode will just be added after the last ```-[[:xdigit:]]{4}``` block instead of at the end. Is there a easy way around?

Comment: @steffen Replace `-[[:xdigit:]]{12}` with `-[[:xdigit:]]+`.

Comment: Works very well! Thanks alot @Wiktor Stribiżew